# no puedo acceder a la propiedad de un objeto devuelto por un promise

Tags: javascript, json, foreach, promesas

Tengo una lista de elementos que proviene de un promise:

```js
const fetchPokemonList = async (offset) => {
        
  //Primero recojo la lista de pokemon de 30 en 30
  const endPoint = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=30&offset=${offset}`;
  const pokemonListRequest = await fetch(endPoint).catch((error) => console.log(error));

  const pokemonAnswer = await pokemonListRequest.json();

  //Despues la recorro para meter la imagen 
  for (let i = 0; i < pokemonAnswer.results.length; i++) {
      const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonAnswer.results[i].name}/`
          fetch(url)
              .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
              .then(resultado => pokemonAnswer.results[i].image = resultado.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default)

  }

  const getIdFromUrl = (url) => {
      const urlPokemonSplit = url.split('/');
      return urlPokemonSplit[urlPokemonSplit.length - 2]
  }

  pokemonAnswer.results.map(({ name, url, image }) => ({
      name,
      url,
      image,
      id: getIdFromUrl(url),
  }));

//Si aquí hago un log, todo está ok
  return pokemonAnswer.results;

}


fetchPokemonList(0).then((pokemonList) => {
  console.log(pokemonList) 
  pokemonList.forEach(pokemonItem => {
    console.log(pokemonItem.name)
          console.log(pokemonItem.url)
          console.log(pokemonItem.image) //este devuelve undefined 
  });
});
```

y se devuelve correctamente:

La pokemonList me devuelve una lista de pokemon con name, url e image, tal y como debe ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando recorro la lista, las propiedades name y url de cada elemento los devuelve bien, pero la imagen aparece como undefined y en la consola se muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, no aparece en la vista general de cada elemento pero al desplegar está ahí...

¿Alguien puede explicarme lo que ocurre? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Es una API pública de Pokemon? ¿Puedes poner el endpoint al que estás llamando?

Comment: sí, edito pregunta y lo añado, disculpa y gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una condición de carrera. La consola del navegador te está liando porque muestra los objetos cargándolos de manera perezosa. Lo que está ocurriendo es lo siguiente:

1. Obtienes la lista de pokemon.
2. Para cada elemento, pides más detalles con un nuevo `fetch`.
3. Devuelves la lista de pokemon.
4. Muestras los resultados en la consola (aún no tenemos la url de la imagen).
5. Las llamadas individuales a `fetch` se completan y se añade la URL a la imagen para cada elemento.

Podemos ver que esto es lo que pasa añadiendo mensajes:

```js
const fetchPokemonList = async (offset) => {
        
  //Primero recojo la lista de pokemon de 30 en 30
  const endPoint = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=30&offset=${offset}`;
  const pokemonListRequest = await fetch(endPoint).catch((error) => console.log(error));

  const pokemonAnswer = await pokemonListRequest.json();

  //Despues la recorro para meter la imagen 
  for (let i = 0; i < pokemonAnswer.results.length; i++) {
      const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonAnswer.results[i].name}/`
          fetch(url)
              .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
              .then(resultado => {
                  pokemonAnswer.results[i].image = resultado.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default;
                  console.log('Imagen obtenida para el pokemon', pokemonAnswer.results[i].name);
              });

  }

  const getIdFromUrl = (url) => {
      const urlPokemonSplit = url.split('/');
      return urlPokemonSplit[urlPokemonSplit.length - 2]
  }

  pokemonAnswer.results.map(({ name, url, image }) => ({
      name,
      url,
      image,
      id: getIdFromUrl(url),
  }));

//Si aquí hago un log, todo está ok
  return pokemonAnswer.results;

}


fetchPokemonList(0).then((pokemonList) => {
  pokemonList.forEach(pokemonItem => {
    console.log(pokemonItem.name)
          console.log(pokemonItem.url)
          console.log(pokemonItem.image) //este devuelve undefined 
  });
});
```

Una solución sería esperar a que todas esas nuevas promesas se resuelvan:

```js
const fetchPokemonList = async (offset) => {
        
  //Primero recojo la lista de pokemon de 30 en 30
  const endPoint = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=30&offset=${offset}`;
  const pokemonListRequest = await fetch(endPoint).catch((error) => console.log(error));

  const pokemonAnswer = await pokemonListRequest.json();

  //Despues la recorro para meter la imagen 
  let promises = pokemonAnswer.results.map( pokemon => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}/`;
    return fetch(url)
      .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
      .then(resultado => {
        pokemon.image = resultado.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default;
        console.log('Imagen obtenida para el pokemon', pokemon.name);
      });
  })
  
  //esperamos a todas las promesas
  await Promise.all(promises);
  
  const getIdFromUrl = (url) => {
      const urlPokemonSplit = url.split('/');
      return urlPokemonSplit[urlPokemonSplit.length - 2]
  }

  return pokemonAnswer.results.map(({ name, url, image }) => ({
      name,
      url,
      image,
      id: getIdFromUrl(url),
  }));
}


fetchPokemonList(0).then((pokemonList) => {
  pokemonList.forEach(pokemonItem => {
    console.log(pokemonItem.name)
          console.log(pokemonItem.url)
          console.log(pokemonItem.image) //este devuelve undefined 
  });
});
```

Comment: Exacto. Funciona perfectamente. Muchísimas gracias amigo!!!